# How to catch and save json data posted to restful asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I have this code:

```
[Route]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostData[FromBody] DataModel data)
    {
         ... implementation...
    }
```

This automatically binds / converts the json data to my data model. However, I would like to save / catch the raw json file that was posted and save it for logging purposes.
Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do the below and then use JSON converter to convert the string to JSON later.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostData([FromBody] string text)
{
   // log text.
    DataModel data = JsonConvert.DeSerialize<DataModel>(text);
}
```

Or you can also do,

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostData()
{
    string text = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; 
    //log text           
    DataModel data = JsonConvert.DeSerialize<DataModel>(text);
}
```

Since you mention it is for logging, you might want to consider doing this in a Web API filter or a delegating handler - to make the logic more centralized instead of having the logic in each action method.

```
public class LogApiRequest : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var text =  actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            MyLogger.Log(LogLevel.INFO, text);

            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
    }
```

and then register your filter - typically in WebApiConfig.cs or decorate your action method or controller class with the filter.

```
config.Filters.Add(new LogApiRequest());
```

Comment: hi govin, I tried the first option string text as parameter and it is always null. If I change that to object instead of string, I see the content, but not sure if that is the correct way.

Comment: Ideally I will be later creating the filter as you suggested, however I just tried to read that within the PostData method and the var text is "" all the time. Any ideas?

Comment: That's weird. What version of Web API do you use? I also posted one more alternative. See if that works for you..

Comment: I am using web api 2.0. Strange, I could not read it inside the method, but the same line of code worked in the filter. Shouldnt it be the same Request? Thanks for your help mate

Comment: Ok, running more tests, I realized that it works if I override the OnAuthorization method. If I override the OnActionExecuting, it is always empty ""